# onerror event not called on img element in windows UWP app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to show a default image if image is not found for ***img*** tag. So in below html code, since **invalid.jpg** is not available, it should load animals image instead.

`<img src="invalid.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';"/>`

The above code works fine when I run this in browser. I can see that animals image getting loaded in the img tag. However when I run the same code in windows html5 desktop app on windows 10, then instead of animal image I see a broken image loaded in img tag.

**Broken image on win10**

[image: Broken image on win10]

So basically onerror event is not getting raised in windows 10 app. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: UWP app does not support inline JS code. You have to put your logic to your background js file to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your event "error" doesn't work because there is no error.

Comment: alt is to provide text when image is not found. it doesnt support image